# Are all packages also modules in Node?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I've read [npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules), but still couple of my concepts are still unclear which may seem naive, are as follows:

Q1.

> A package is a file or directory that is described by a package.json
>   file.

What do they meant by **"described by a `package.json` file"**? Any example to understand easily?

Q2.

**Condition to be a package**

> A package is a file or directory that is described by a package.json
>   file.

**Condition to be a module**

> To be loaded by the Node.js require() function, a module must be one
>   of the following:
>
> - A folder with a package.json file containing a "main" field.
> - A folder with an index.js file in it.
> - A JavaScript file.
>
> **Note**: Since modules are not required to have a package.json file, not
>   all modules are packages. Only modules that have a package.json file
>   are also packages.

So, as per the **Note**, shouldn't it also implies that all packages are also modules as all packages have package.json files?

Answer (score 2):

A module is anything that can be loaded with `require()` and does something useful.  It can be a single file.  It does not need to have a package.json associated with it.  In fact, many locally developed "modules" do not.  You can have many modules in the same directory.

A package is a set of code designed for easy distribution.  If you are using the NPM package manager, then an NPM package will contain a package.json file that has a bunch of meta data about the package, including things like dependencies on other modules, author info, repository info, info on how to test the module, info on which file is the startup file for the module, etc...

FYI, NPM is not the only package manager so it's not the only way of doing things, but for node.js development it is certainly the most widely used and it offers a central repository that makes it easy the "publish" packages for wide and simple distribution.

> Are all packages also modules in Node?

I suppose it's possible to distribute something other than runnable code in a package, but the primary use of an NPM package is to distribute modules.

Here's an example of destributing static data rather than code: [JSON Data Node Modules Part 1: Using NPM to Store and Distribute Static Data](https://www.credera.com/blog/mobile-applications-and-web/json-data-node-modules-part-1-using-npm-to-store-and-distribute-static-data/).

Comment: I understand everything you mentioned but when you said "You can have many modules in the same file." Do you have any doc link I can refer to? because as per the npm doc it does satisfy either of the 3 conditions.

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 - I meant to say you can have many modules in the same directory, not file. Keep in mind that a module is a [node.js thing](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), not an NPM thing.  NPM puts one or more node.js modules into a package.

Comment: one last thing, can you come up with an example when some packages are not modules?

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 - I don't know if that's done much, but you could distribute data files in an NPM package that are meant to be read other ways besides being loaded as a module.  At its lowest level, an NPM package is a bundle of files.  When used for distributing modules, `package.json` contains lots of useful metadata, but if it was used for distributing other kinds of files, you could just install the package and read the data files with your own code.  For example, you could put a song play list in a text file and distribute it via an NPM package.  This is not how NPM is normally used.

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 - FYI: [JSON Data Node Modules Part 1: Using NPM to Store and Distribute Static Data](https://www.credera.com/blog/mobile-applications-and-web/json-data-node-modules-part-1-using-npm-to-store-and-distribute-static-data/).  Static data rather than code.